# "req.session.user = user" where user is not defined

Tags: node.js, session

I had read almost every possible threads, post, questions, I got on setting session cookies, still didn't get the perfect solution.

I had created a web application where I want to set sessions cookies who had logged in.

Not able to figure out why the "user" is undefined. Where did I lack? I had did every trail and error to figure out the error.

**App.js file**

```
const session = require('client-sessions');    
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'sessioncookie',
  secret: 'long_string_which_is_hard_to_crack',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));
```

**Routes.js file**

```
 router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
            const emaild = req.body.email;
            const passd = req.body.pass;

            db.collection('check').findOne({email: emaild}, (err, result) => {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                console.log(result.passcode);
                console.log('Retrived from database');

                bcrypt.compare(passd, result.passcode, function(err, boolean) { 
                    console.log(boolean);
                    if(boolean == true) {
                        req.session.user = user; //// It's Undefined
                        res.redirect('/dashboard');
                    } else {
                        res.send('<h1>Wrong Password</h1>');
                    }
          });
       });
    });
```

Comment: *user* is the same item you've retrieved from database, here you name it `result` so you should use: `req.session.user = result;`

Comment: I had changed it to req.session.user = result; but still, => Cannot set property 'user' of undefined. I had also tried it with "result.email" which is the email address of user derived from the database.

Comment: It means `req.session` is undefined. looking at [client-sessions documentation](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) seems it attachs session by `cookieName` property value to req; so you should use: `req.sessioncookie.user = result;`

Comment: I tried it too but still no change. Same error. Hey, I had uploaded the full code here [on github](https://github.com/Sowmayjain/aws-email). Can you help me figure out the problem? Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Middlewares ordering matters. move your session middlewares before this one: `app.use('/', routes);`

Comment: Wow! It works. Thanks. Thank you very much. Why don't you consider writing an independent answer on it? Others with similar query might benefits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134884/discussion-between-sowmay-jain-and-dnitro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you query your collection with `findOne` method it will return you the related document ( here `user` which you name it `result` ) and you should name it with a meaningful parameter like `user` and then `user` becames available within this callback function.

Also when you get the following error on `req.session.user = user;`:

> Cannot set property 'user' of undefined

It means that `req.session` is `undefined`. Using express, setting `session` on request is doing by `session middlewares`. here you are using [client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) which attachs session by `cookieName` option value you pass it at initialization. so you should set it like the following:

```
req.sessioncookie.user = user;
```

Note that **middleware ordering does matters**. you should configure you application using middlewares before setting up your routes. this way every incoming request is populated with desired configuration you have been set up.